# when save excel file on angular 8 get error Failed to execute createObjectURL?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-material, angular8, angular-components

I work on `angular 8` I face issue when save excel file I get error as below :

```
ERROR TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
    at Function.a [as saveAs] (FileSaver.min.js:1:1339)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (zdeliverysys.component.ts:225:23)
```

what i try is :

```
component ts

  this._dataService.PostUpload(this.fileToUpload)
      .subscribe(blob => {
      saveAs(blob.body, this.fileToUpload +'.xlsx');
       });
service.ts
  PostUpload( file:any):Observable<any>
  {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file,file.name);
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'Z2Delivery/Upload' , formData,{responseType: 'blob' });
   
  }
```

How to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue
i modify service response on angular

from

```
 return this.http.post(this.url + 'Z2Delivery/Upload' , formData,{responseType: 'blob' });
```

to

```
return this.http.post(this.url + 'Z2Delivery/Upload' , formData,{observe: 'response',responseType: 'blob' });
```

and excel file download success without any problem